# How does Excel RTD invoke IRtdServer.DisconnectData()?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, rtd

It's easy enough to invoke `ConnectData()` with `=RTD()` in Excel.

But there's also a function `DisconnectData()`.  Is there some Excel function that will cause `DisconnectData()` to be called?

What is this method for, really?

Comment: There was a bug in the released version of Excel 2010 related to the DisconnectData call. It is fixed in Office 2010 SP1 and later, and documented here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ba06ac78-7b64-449b-bce4-9a03ac91f0eb/excel-2010-and-rtd-bug?forum=exceldev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you delete the `RTD()` call in all cells that reference that topicID, `DisconnectData()` gets called.

So obvious in retrospect.